# Ubuntu server - port forwarding

Tags: server, iptables, port-forwarding

I need to redirect from http port 80 to elsewhere to specific page, which running on port 9090/somepage.

In short:

Need redirect x.x.x.x:80 -> x.x.x.x:9090/page

I tried to do by command iptable, but I not be able to redirect port to specific port and page (only port to another port).

Please how I can realize this?

Answer (score 0):

In order to redirect from ip1:port to ip2:port you will need some software in addition to iptables. First you should make sure that iptables properly routes from one port to the new port.

You can review the accepted answer in this question to modify the page that is displayed. Generally this is index.html by default.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19322345/how-do-i-change-the-default-index-page-in-apache

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question somewhat, but this solution should still suffice.

Comment: I know but this solution is "dirty". Do you know some software to solve this problem please ?

Comment: This is a cleaner solution. I'm sure there is a better way, but this is much better than the previous.